# 20.04.1 lts mmap failed on hugetlbfs file

Tags: kernel, mount

```
mmap() fails on hugetlbfs file.
julu@julu-lap:~$ pwd
/home/julu
julu@julu-lap:~$ uname -a
Linux julu-lap 5.8.0-36-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 6 10:15:55 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
julu@julu-lap:~$ ls /dev/hugepages/
libvirt
julu@julu-lap:~$ mount | grep huge
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
julu@julu-lap:~$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-36-generic root=UUID=8fa78c96-50d3-4db8-8a27-f96a328706b8 ro quiet splash hugepagesz=1G hugepages=1 hugepagesz=2M hugepages=128 vt.ha
```

even with hugetlbfs configured,  mmap() of a hugetlb backed file -- fails on this ubuntu.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

looks like MMAP of a hugeTLB backed file is not working.  MAP_SHARED of hugeTLB is not available.  i got around my problem by just using a MMAP of a hugeTLB page using - MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_HUGETLB|MAP_HUGE_1G|MAP_ANONNYMOUS. flags on the mmap call.

This can be a wrinkle on use of 'dpdk/spdk' usermode NVME/Network application users.